# Bigquery - How to select top 50 elements based on a aggregated column, grouped over 3 columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Example table

| FN | LN | City | id | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| may | son | lalitpur | 1 | a |
| may | son | lalitpur | 2 | c |
| may | son | lalitpur | 3 | a |
| may | son | jhansi | 4 | a |
| may | son | jhansi | 11 | a |
| may | son | varansi | 4 | a |
| may | son | kanpur | 11 | a |
| may | ton | jhansi | 4 | a |
| day | son | jhansi | 11 | a |

I need to find top x cities based on distinct id for each unique pair of FN,LN columns.

Output if selecting top 2 values

| FN | LN | City | unique Ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| may | son | lalitpur | 4 |
| may | son | jhansi. | 2 |
| may | ton | jhansi. | 1 |
| day | son | jhansi. | 1 |

With following sql I have got the data but I can't filter based on uniquq ids

```
           SELECT
                FN,
                LN,
                City,
                count(distinct(userId)) as unique_ids
            FROM
                 tableName
            WHERE
                <some condition>
            group by
                1,
                2,
                3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation with window functions like this:

```
select x.* except (seqnum)
from (select fn, ln, city, count(distinct id) as unique_ids,
             row_number() over (partition by fn, ln order by count(distinct id) desc) as seqnum
      from tableName t
      group by fn, ln, city
     ) x
where seqnum <= 50;
```

A simpler way to write this uses the very recently introduced `qualify` clause:

```
select fn, ln, city, count(distinct id) as unique_ids
from tableName t
group by fn, ln, city
qualify row_number() over (partition by fn, ln order by count(distinct id) desc) <= 50;
```

Or:

```
select fn, ln, city, count(distinct id) as unique_ids
from tableName t
group by fn, ln, city
qualify row_number() over (partition by fn, ln order by unique_ids desc) <= 50;
```

Comment: also I think you don't need to repeat `count(distinct id)` in `qualify` clause and rather can use calculated already `unique_ids` - so it can be like `qualify row_number() over (partition by fn, ln order by unique_ids desc) <= 50;`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . Good suggestion.